# Why is textarea.value returning "undefined"? (using Native Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, click, textarea

This is really simple but I just cant figure out what is Wrong.

I got a `div`, a `textarea`, a `button`.

I want to use **"Native-Javascript"** coz lately i have been using `jQuery` alot and I want to go Native on this basic thing.

The Aim is to get the contents of the `enter code here`textarea transfered to the  `div` and have the same logged in the `console` on `button`'s `click`.

See my Codes:

*Javascript:*

```
function text_func (){
    var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
        div_out = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        txt_a = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

    console.log(txt_a.value);// This Logs undefined :: WHY?

        //return;
        btn[0].addEventListener('click',btn_click,false);

        function btn_click(){

            console.log(txt_a.value)//  This also logs undefined.. Why again?
            div_out.innerHTML = txt_a.value;

            }

    }

window.onload = function(){

    text_func();    

    }
```

*HTML:*

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:300px; border:1px solid #ccc; height:100px; padding:10px;"></div>

<textarea style="width:300px; border:1px solid #ccc; height:100px; padding:10px;"></textarea>

<button>Go</button>
```

What I'm I doing wrong?....

**See Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3urm9/
Any Suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
console.log(txt_a[0].value)
```

Notice the `[0]`

Comment: Thanks,Thanx it worked as expected. I think I need some serious `Native-Javascript` tutorials

Comment: @UniversalGrasp: If you're not supporting IE6/7 (hopefully that's the case), you can use `.querySelector()` to get a single element using css selectors. `document.querySelector("textarea").value`.

Comment: @cookiemonster thanks alot... but what do you think will be the safest? just in case? thx again.

Comment: @UniversalGrasp: If you need to support `IE6` or `IE7`, then `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` simply won't work. Otherwise, I'd say it's perfectly safe. But `getElementsByTagName()` will work in all browsers.

Comment: document.querySelector("textarea").value worked for me :) Thnks @cookiemonster

Answer (score 1):

```
getElementsByTagName
```

That returns an *array* (actually a NodeList) of elements.
Arrays don't have a `value` property.

You probably want to get one of the elements from the array.